# Avoiding fractional or unnecessary matissa representation when printing number

Tags: output-formatting

I'm trying to generate a series of graphs in which a parameter `mu` varies and is used in the creation of labels within the plot.  I can't seem, however, to get the desired format for the number.  The desired formatting is "mu $= 10^{-5}/$gen", but I either get a long fraction or an unnecessary matissa.

I've tried,

```
mu = 10^-5

unwantedFraction =  StringForm[" mu = ``/gen", ScientificForm[mu, ScientificNotationThreshold -> {-1, 1}]]
unwantedMatissa = StringForm[" mu = ``/gen", ScientificForm[1.*mu, ScientificNotationThreshold -> {-1, 1}]]
```

which gives,

[image]

Any suggestions on how to get the desired $10^{-5}$?

Comment: `StringForm["mu = ``/gen", 10^ToString[Log10[mu]]]`

Answer (score 1):

This is to check:

```
mu1 = 10^-5;
mu2 = 10^6;
```

Try this:

```
     Row[{(" mu =10")^ToString[MantissaExponent[#][[2]] - 1], 
    "/gen"}] &[mu1]
Row[{(" mu =10")^ToString[MantissaExponent[#][[2]] - 1], 
    "/gen"}] &[mu2]
```

To better see it, I show the result as the image:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I should have known it would be complex since it is (a) Mathematica and (b) involves text formatting.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Alexi and Bob's responses, here's my solution (without the extra surrounding strings "mu = " and "/gen" since I will use this more generally).

```
toScientificFormString[val_] := Module[{mantissa, exponent, trim},
  
  If[val == 0, Return[0]]; (*deal with special case*)

  mantissa = 10^(Log10[val] - Floor[Log10[ val]]);
  exponent = Floor[Log10[ val]];
  
  If[Abs[mantissa] == 1,
    StringForm["``", (10^ToString[exponent])],
    StringForm["`` \[Times] ``", 
    NumberForm[(mantissa)], (10^ToString[exponent])]
   ]
  ]

toScientificFormString[mu]
toScientificFormString[2*mu]
toScientificFormString[2.0*mu]
toScientificFormString[2.0/mu]
toScientificFormString[10.0]
```

Which produces

[image: my function output]

Input and suggestions welcome